# Can't Read property innerHTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting the following error: cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null.

Here is the HTML part:

```
<div id="itemcost0">300</div>
```

Now the Javascript part:

```
    itemcount = parseInt(document.getElementById("itemcounter").value);
    var loop = 0;
    while(loop<=itemcount)
    {
        itemprice = parseInt(document.getElementById("itemcost" + loop).innerHTML);
        loop++;
    }
```

Before anyone suggests this, the javascript is located after the table the div itemcost0 is in.  It should also be noted that itemcount has the correct value.

Comment: What is this? `document.getElementById("itemcounter").value` can you add that part of the html?

Comment: Still might be a good idea to wrap this in a function and call it when the document is ready, no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using zero index, so the count is probably one less than the max so

```
while(loop<=itemcount)
```

should probably be

```
while(loop<itemcount)
```

Comment: nice, no one found this :P

Comment: You were correct.  I forgot to subtract 1 from itemcount.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
itemcount = parseInt(document.getElementById("itemcounter").value);
    var loop = 0;
    while(loop<=itemcount)
    {
        itemprice = parseInt(document.getElementById("itemcost" + loop.toString()).innerHTML);
        loop++;
    }
```

loop should be a string not an integer.

Comment: String + Interger = String AKA `"itemcost" + 0 === "itemcost0"`